# How to use Repeater in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, repeater

I'm completely newbie on ASP.net i just want to ask if what does it mean we they say Repeater is Editable? does it mean you can edit it while running on a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Repeater doesn't have `EditTemplate` .

I suggest you to make edit fields in a hidden Placeholder, show this when clicking an edit button.

Here is [In-place Editing with ASP.NET Repeater](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247289/In-place-editing-with-ASP-NET-Repeater) example on CodeProject .

Answer (score 0):

You can Edit and save the content using editable repeater.

Good [documentation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247289/In-place-editing-with-ASP-NET-Repeater) available in code project

Answer (score 0):

*Which* source says a "repeater is editable"? The [Repeater documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests otherwise:

> The Repeater control *has no built-in selection capabilities or editing support.*

By itself a Repeater doesn't allow much of anything except data-binding controls from a collection. Now, one could use [two-way databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.ASPX) to create "editable content", sure .. but that doesn't imply a "repeater is editable".